# How to create custom fixed-width buttons in Foundation 5 using button-group-style mixin

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create a custom button bar centered within a row using Foundation 5 mixins, where the buttons are of the same width based off the size of the largest button in the group. In the vanilla version just adding even-4 to the class would do it, but I cant seem to get the syntax correct for the custom button bar.

HTML

```
<div class="small-12 small-centered columns">
<ul class="top-nav">
<li><a href="#" class="topnavbtn">Instructions</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="topnavbtn">Glossary</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="topnavbtn">Documents</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="topnavbtn">Links</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.top-nav {
    @include button-group-container(true, false);
    text-align:center;
    .topnavbtn {
        $button-border-width: 1px;
        $button-border-style: solid;
        @include button($button-tny, #c0ced7, false, false, false, false);
    }

    & > li {
    @include button-group-style(true, 4);
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
@include button($button-tny, #c0ced7, false, false, false, false);
```

to this:

```
@include button($button-tny, #c0ced7, false, true, false, false);
```

or for more clarity, this:

```
@include button(
  $padding: $button-tny,
  $bg: #c0ced7,
  $full-width: true
);
```

The `even-4` class doesn't really size each button based off the size of the largest button in the group: it assigns a width of 100 / 4 = 25% to each button. The button-group-style mixin that does this also sets the child elements' widths to 100%, which is why the 'vanilla' (i.e., non-custom mixin) version results in nice, evenly-sized buttons. In this case, they'd each occupy 100% of 25% = 25% of the container width.

However, the button mixin, by default, uses padding to determine button size. That is, they are not 100% of the container width unless you pass `$full-width: true`. Because you're using the default of `$full-width: false`, the button-group-style mixin is being overridden by the button mixin and your buttons are evenly-spaced but different sizes.